# Identifying specific replica in kubernetes deployment programmatically

Tags: .net, kubernetes

Let's suppose a K8s cluster exists with a deployment with 3 replicas (shouldn't be relevant, but let's suppose it is an AKS cluster).

The container runs .NET 6 code with the K8s .NET client library. We can read the host pod id, but can we read the host pod replica number?

For example, let's suppose the 3 replicas are hosted in pods named podA, podB, podC.
Then podB crashes. K8s will restart the replica but with a different pod name, let's say podD.
How can I find, programmatically, that the just started pod is exactly the resuscitated podB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, When a pod crashes, k8s doesn't necessarily change the name of the pod, Because as you said, it's restarted, not recreated. Restart will appear and number will increase incrementally in `RESTARTS` column of `kubectl get pods -n <namespace>` command output. If every restart would create a new pod, there would not have been necessary to have `RESTARTS` column in the first place.

Second, in your example, there is no way to assign `PodB`'s totally random name to `PodD` in deployment. Because k8s assigning them to deployment pods randomly. If you want to accomplish this, you should use `StatefulSet` instead of `Deployment` Because each pod in a StatefulSet has a unique and stable network identity.

As k8s document points ;

`Like a Deployment, a StatefulSet manages Pods that are based on an identical container spec. Unlike a Deployment, a StatefulSet maintains a sticky identity for each of their Pods. These pods are created from the same spec, but are not interchangeable: each has a persistent identifier that it maintains across any rescheduling.`

Reference : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/